# Django {% if object.foreignkey %} returns the opposite of the value

Tags: python, django, if-statement, templates, foreign-keys

So I have two models.

First one is Collection Title and second one is Title Status.
In Title Status I have a foreignkey named collection_title_status that points to CollectionTitle.

I have rendered the form TitleStatusForm  inside my collection_title_detail.html with a DetailView and a FormMixin. The form is in a modal.

Globally, this part works, meaning that I can fill the form, and it saves the data and creates a link between the Collection Title and the Foreign Key of Title Status (for example, if CollectionTitle id is 61, my collection_title_status value will be 61 as well).

What I want to do :

- If Collection Title is not linked to a Title Status (meaning the user as not initiate the Status monitoring yet), then I want to display the button called 'Initiate' that opens the modal containing TitleStatusForm to initiate the Title Status model
- If Collection Title is already linked to a Title Status (which should be done after fulfilling the first step above), then I don't want to display the above mentionned button and modal. Instead, I want to display the values previously entered by the user for each field.

So here is how I tried to do it :

models.py (I did not include the different choices on purpose)

```
class CollectionTitle(models.Model):
    collection = models.ForeignKey(Collection,
    related_name="has_titles", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=CHOICES, default=MOBILE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

class TitleStatus(models.Model):
    collection_title_status = models.ForeignKey(CollectionTitle, related_name="has_status", on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    is_active = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=IS_ACTIVE, null=True)
    check_one = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=IS_DONE, null=True)
    check_one_date = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)
```

views.py

```
class CollectionTitlesDetail(LoginRequiredMixin, FormMixin, DetailView):
    model = CollectionTitle
    form_class = TitleStatusForm
    template_name = 'taskflow/collection_titles_detail.html'
    success_url = None

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(CollectionTitlesDetail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['tgt_titles'] = CollectionTitle.objects.filter(collection=self.object.collection)
        context['checks'] = TitleStatusForm()
        return context

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    form = TitleStatusForm(request.POST)
    tgt = self.get_object()

    if form.is_valid():
        new_status = form.save(commit=False)
        new_status.collection_title_status = tgt
        new_status.is_active = 'Actif'
        new_status.save()
        return redirect('taskflow:collection_titles')
    else:
        return redirect('taskflow:collection_all')
```

collection_titles_detail.html

```
{% if object.has_status %}
  <p>TRUE</p> #to test it I just wrote this
{% else %}
  display button + modal to initiate Status
{% endif %}
```

So, according to the above codes, if I run the server and go for example to /collection/titles/31/, I should be able to see the Initiate button because there are no Title Status linked to Collection title with id 31. (Actually there is no Title Status in the database at all). But instead I get the

TRUE

result..

If I change the if condition to if not, I get the initiate button... whereas I sould get TRUE..

Lastly, if I do :

```
{% if not object.has_status %}
    display button + modal to initiate Status 
{% else %}
    <p>TRUE</p> #to test it I just wrote this
{% endif %}
```

I get TRUE again whereas I sould get the Initiate button...

So there is something I clearly do wrong and that I clearly don't undrstand.

Any help woul be appreciate.

Thanks a lot !!

Answer (score 0):

`has_status` is a [`RelatedManager`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager) and will always be "True", you need to execute a query on the manager to determine if there are any related objects. [`exists`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.exists) is the simplest query to perform for this

```
{% if not object.has_status.exists %}
    display button + modal to initiate Status 
{% endif %}
```